# Firestore Database trying to get data using another file

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

here is my code from my **main_menu_password.dart**, in this file i want display the data i get from another file

```
class MainMenuPassword extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainMenuPassword({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainMenuPassword> createState() => _MainMenuPasswordState();
}

class _MainMenuPasswordState extends State<MainMenuPassword> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var passwordWarehaouse = WarehousePassword.value;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(passwordWarehaouse),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Warehouse'),
                  onPressed: () => screenLock(
                      context: context,
                      correctString: GetPassword.value, //<<== Firestore data here
                      title: const Text('Warehouse'),
                      onUnlocked: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => WarehousePassword(),
                            ),
                          ),
                      onCancelled: Navigator.of(context).pop),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Sales'),
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code from "get_password.dart" in this file i tryibg to get data in and pas it to main_menu_password.dart

```
class GetPassword extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetPassword({super.key});
  static var value = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('dataPassword');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      future: collection.doc('eh7eZiBeX24a6KSuI7Jc').get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var data = snapshot.data!.data();
          value = data!['warehousePassword'];
        }
        return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my database
[Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6M9x.png)

how i can query in another file like "**get_password.dart**" to get "**warehousePassword**" data in my firestore database and i pass that data to **main_menu_password.dart** so i can using the value from my firestore database file.

Comment: are you using uid as doc id? can you include how you are saving it

Comment: no, i don't using uid as a doc id. the doc id automatic create by firebase. i save the data by manually create in firebase console not from code

Comment: Add your get_password.dart file to the question.

Comment: If it's extremely too long you can just add the portion you have retrieved the password

Comment: sorry about that i forgot add the file, i already update it, please help thanks.